# python filepath is not defined name error

Tags: python, nameerror

This is the code I am using and I get an error with the filepath I have the file in the same folder with everything else.

```
# imports
import csv
import json
import dash
import pandas as pd
import sys, getopt, pprint, os
import pymongo
import numpy as np
import dash_leaflet as dl
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import base64

import os
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash import dash_table
from pprint import pprint
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from bson.json_util import dumps
from pymongo import MongoClient
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dbCRUD import BidSystem

##### THIS SECTION ONLY NEEDED FOR INITIAL SETUP #####
# Setup to import the csv file into mongodb through mongodb atlas
#def import_content(filepath):

    # Provide the mongodb atlas url to connect python to mongodb using pymongo and create a connection using MongoClient
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://myAdminUser:abcd1234@cluster0.zxsdm.mongodb.net/mongodb_eBids?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
    # details for the database and collection names
mng_db = client['mongodb_eBids']
collection_name = 'eBids'
db_cm = mng_db[collection_name]
    #setup to pull the data from csv file and insert into mongodb as json data
cdir = (os.path.dirname(__file__))
file_res = (os.path.join(cdir, filepath))
data = pd.read_csv(file_res)
data_json = json.loads(data.to_json(orient='records'))
db_cm.remove()
db_cm.insert(data_json)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    filepath = 'eBids.csv'
    import_content(filepath)
###### THIS SECTION ONLY NEEDED FOR INITIAL SETUP #####
```

Comment: `filepath` is defined at the bottom of the script, but you refer to it above that, before it is defined.  The code is executed in order beginning at the top of the file.

Comment: When I move the filepath = 'eBids.csv' to above that section then it makes the import_content(filepath) give the name error for import_content.

Comment: The function definition for `import_content` is commented out, so yes indeed, that function is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you commented the function definition. Uncomment this line try again
`#def import_content(filepath):`

Comment: its always something simple thank you